# Error when using custom IdentityUser class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've changed table names in asp.net core 2.2 but i get the following error

```
InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered.
```

I think I did everything.  This is my current code.

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

THis is my dbcontext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("User");
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("UserClaim");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("UserRole");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("RoleClaim");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToTable("UserToken");
    }
}
```

and this is my model for ApplicationUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

What have I missed?  I beleive I got everything.

Comment: Can you please add your Controller code? You're probably trying to inject `UserManager<IdentityUser>` instead of `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`

Comment: It was in my _LoginPartial. THank you

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your `Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml` file. Currently your `_LoginPartial.cshtml` containing:

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
```

Which must be changed to:

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```